# Error post request Ajax to database (Laravel)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

So, basically I tried to create a user registration system in Laravel. The registration form modal works well when I press the Add Button, but after posted some data I found an error.

**app.blade.php**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>
```

**My Modal Form**

```
<div id="addModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" autofocus>
                                <small>Min: 2, Max: 32, only text</small>
                                <p class="errorTitle text-center alert alert-danger hidden"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="content">Content:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="email" name="email" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
                                <small>Min: 2, Max: 128, only text</small>
                                <p class="errorContent text-center alert alert-danger hidden"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add" data-dismiss="modal">
                             Add
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
                             Close
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**My Javascript to post data**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('click', '.add-modal', function() {
            $('.modal-title').text('Add');
            $('#addModal').modal('show');
        });

        $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.add', function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
              }
            });

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "{{ route('users.store') }} ",
                data: {
                    '_token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'),
                    'name': $('#name').val(),
                    'email': $('#email').val()
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

                    if ((data.errors)) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#addModal').modal('show');
                            toastr.error('Validation error!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                        }, 500);

                        if (data.errors.title) {
                            $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                        }
                        if (data.errors.content) {
                            $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
                        }
                    } else {
                        toastr.success('Successfully added Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                        $('#postTable').append("<tr class='item" + data.id + "'><td>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.title + "</td><td>" + data.content + "</td><td class='text-center'><input type='checkbox' class='new_published' data-id='" + data.id + " '></td><td>Right now</td><td><button class='show-modal btn btn-success' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-title='" + data.title + "' data-content='" + data.content + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span> Show</button> <button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-title='" + data.title + "' data-content='" + data.content + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-title='" + data.title + "' data-content='" + data.content + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</button></td></tr>");
                        $('.new_published').on('ifToggled', function(event){
                            $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('warning');
                        });
                    }
                },
            });
        });
  </script>
```

**User.php (Modal)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Response;
use App\User;
use View;


class UsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $group = array(
            '1'=>'Administrator',
            '2'=>'Operator',
        );

        $users = User::all();
        return view('admin.users.index', compact('users', 'group'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->save();
        return response()->json($user);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'site is building!';
});

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
#Route::get('users-json', 'UsersController@json')->name('users-json'); // WARNING
```

My Error log in browser console is :

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/users 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Go to your `network` during inspect. I think you will find exact error there

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) means that the problem is in PHP code, look into the network tab -> response of the browser to see the actual exception thrown

Comment: @RashedHasan you are so genius.

Comment: you too @CaddyDZ

Comment: Thats work.!!!!